# Typecasting a function pointer

Tags: c, function-pointers, typecast-operator

I know this is a duplicate. I've searched already but none address the problem I'm having.
**NOTE** in an attempt to single out my confusion I have tried to simplify the typecast from the original. Hopefully it isn't undefined behaviour

Declaring a pointer to a function

```
Int (*funcPtr)(void*,void*);
```

Strcmp declaration

```
int strcmp (char *, char *);
```

Typecasting a function pointer

```
FuncPtr = (int (*)(void*, void*))strcmp
```

This is where I get confused. I understand Typecasting a function pointer we have created. So type casting **FuncPtr** for example just changes what type of function **funcPtr** can point to. I have also read that the name of a function Is a function pointer to itself so Typecasting **strcmp** and using my understanding from above,

```
int (*)(void*, void*))strcmp
```

**Strcmp** can now point to a function that takes two pointers to void and returns an int which Is clearly wrong as like arrays I think the function name can't be a pointer to another function.

Because of my understanding above I fail to see how you can assign the address of **strcmp** to **FuncPtr**  with the following typecast

```
FuncPtr = (int (*)(void*, void*))strcmp
```

As changing what the function pointer **strcmp** points to doesn't change the arguments and return type of **strcmp**.

I would really appreciate some knowledge I'm just so confused.

Comment: Well, just because you can, doesn't mean it's a good idea.  I can drive my car into a tree if I want to, but....

Comment: Any function pointer can point to any function but you are not allowed to call the function through the pointer unless the pointed-to type exactly matches the function being pointed to

Comment: "I think the function name can't be a pointer to another function"  Eh? What do you even mean here? And what is `FuncPtr`, what type? Please note that the C language is case-sensitive.

Comment: If the question is simply "can I have a function pointer of type `int (*)(void*, void*))` and then cast the address of `strcmp` to that type?" then I can answer it. All the other things in your question makes it unclear, however. Also for the record, strcmp has the following format, which matters here: `int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);`.

Comment: What I mean is by typecasting strcmp changes what strcmp points to. However I don't think it's possible to change what strcmp points to

Comment: Simply put Funcptr = (int (*)(void*, void*))strcmp

Comment: Simply put Funcptr = (int (*)(void*, void*))strcmp is logically equivalent to Funcptr = strcmp to me because I fail to see how typecasting strcmp changes the arguments and return type of strcmp to match that of Funcptr for assignment

Comment: @M.M does it have to exactly match? Or can I call a `int(*foo)(int, int)` using `int (*foo) (int, ...);` (with 2 arguments ofcourse and second one being `int` too). I have seen this a lot.

Comment: Nope doesn't matter to me

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya The parameters have to match exactly. Some systems may use non-standard extensions for function pointers. It is also a common non-standard extension to allow function pointers to get cast to `void*`.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya in Standard C it has to be an exact match. Anything else is non-standard extensions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are functions and there are function pointers. `strcmp` is a function, linked to your project. When the identifier `strcmp` is used in an expression, you get a function pointer to that function. But you cannot change "where strcmp points to" because `strcmp` is a function and not a pointer.

C allows conversions between different function pointer types. However, should you try to call a function through a function pointer of incompatible type, you invoke undefined behavior.

```
int (*funcPtr)(void*,void*);
```

is not compatible with `strcmp`, which has the following format:

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

Meaning:

```
funcPtr = (int(*)(void*, void*))strcmp; // this is ok but not very meaningful
funcPtr(); // this is NOT ok, invokes undefined behavior
```

In order to actually call the function `strcmp` through that function pointer, you would have to cast back to the correct type, which is `int (*)(const char*, const char*)`.

Comment: "A function name (label) is converted to a pointer to itself." http://denniskubes.com/2013/03/22/basics-of-function-pointers-in-c/ the last chapter discusses this

Comment: I'm still cunfused as to what the cast (int(*)(void*, void*) does to strcmp? Does it change the argument type to void and return type to int

Comment: @Simple It does nothing whatsoever to strcmp, for the same reason as `int x=0; char* ptr = &x;` does nothing to `x`. The pointer holds an address to the pointed-at item. Just because you let a pointer of a different type point to your variable, that doesn't change the type of the variable itself.